# Getting massenger photo url

Tags: facebook-messenger

Is there any option to download what means getting url of every photo I receive in Facebook Messenger?
I mean  primarily JavaScript but please give any idea you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Python fbchat module, you can access the conversations there so you should be able to download photos from them

Comment: Now I can fetch messages but still this way it's not possible to get image message id. `messages = client.fetchThreadMessages(thread_id=thread_id, limit=10)` There is function `fetchImageUrl`  which returns url but how to get image_id to pass as an argument